# How to run sql files containing load data infile statements

Tags: mysql, sql, scripting, load, load-data-infile

I have a substantial amount of data in XML files that needs to be loaded into MySQL database.

i.e. in year 2012 folder, i have about 52 xml files, and one loadStatements.sql query file for all XML. The loadStatements.sql has the following lines...just a few here.

```
use uspto2012;
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'H:/uspto_db/mysql/2012/ipa120126/ipa120126-01_sql.xml' INTO TABLE       assignee ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<assignee>';
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'H:/uspto_db/mysql/2012/ipa120126/ipa120126-01_sql.xml' INTO TABLE     claims ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<claims>';
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'H:/uspto_db/mysql/2012/ipa120126/ipa120126-01_sql.xml' INTO TABLE description ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<description>';
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'H:/uspto_db/mysql/2012/ipa120126/ipa120126-01_sql.xml' INTO TABLE info ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<info>';
```

Now if I call this file from MySQL workbench or shell, it runs ok. Now I have hundreds of these files and It is tidious to load each file manually.

I need one master file that can call these load files. i.e

```
use uspto2012;
SOURCE H:/uspto_db/mysql/2012/ipa120126/loadStatements.sql;
SOURCE H:/uspto_db/mysql/2012/ipa120202/loadStatements.sql;
SOURCE H:/uspto_db/mysql/2012/ipa120209/loadStatements.sql;
SOURCE H:/uspto_db/mysql/2012/ipa120216/loadStatements.sql;
```

But when I try to run this file, I get error, from mwb. "Source is not recognized as MySQL command"

I kindly need help on a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

`SOURCE` is mysql CLI command.

If you already created your master file you can do this though

```
C:\> mysql -uuser -p < H:/path/to/your/matser_file.sql
```

or

```
C:\> mysql -uuser -p -e "source H:/path/to/your/matser_file.sql"
```

Comment: the master file has thousands of these lines `code`SOURCE H:/uspto_db/mysql/2012/ipa120126/loadStatements.sql; `code` what I need is how to call only one master file and let the process call each source... sequentially until all is done.

Comment: I understand that from your question. And the answer shows **exactly** how achieve what you want with command line mysql.